# How can I make Mathematica return a series expansion in the form $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \dots$ instead of $a_0 + a_1x^1 + \dots + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ O(x^n)$

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, series-expansion, expression-manipulation, recursion

I have a function
$$\phi(x) = \sqrt{(x-t)^2 + c^2},$$
and I want an asymptotic expression for it as $x \to \infty$.

Using the following code I can calculated such an expression:

```
Series[Sqrt[c^2 + (t - x)^2], {x, Infinity, 4}]
```

and the result is
$$
x-t+c^2/(2 x)+(c^2 t)/(2 x^2)+(-(c^4/8)+(c^2 t^2)/2)/x^3+(-((3 c^4 t)/8)+(c^2 t^3)/2)/x^4+O[1/x]^5
$$

However I don't want the answer to be expressed as several terms up to some order. I want it it to be expressed as a summation formula. Mathematica obviously has calculated this formula as it is using it to give me back the function up to a certain order. How can I make it return the actual summation formula? That is, how can I make it give me back the expression in the form?

$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \dots $

Comment: I have an answer in the Form of a DifferenceRoot. It evaluates to rather large formulas for concrete n's. But i can show it if you want. (But I don't think, this will help you)

Comment: @JulienKluge  How do you obtain the `DifferenceRoot` answer? I can obtain that for expansion about `0` but not for expansion about `Infinity`.

Comment: Ah sorry I made a mistake in my code. It now returns a `Indeterminate`...it fails to do the Limit of a general DifferenceRoot answer obtained by the new MMA11.1 feature to make parameterized multiple derivatives.

Comment: @bbgodfrey `SeriesCoefficient[Sqrt[c^2 + (u)^2], {u, Infinity, n}]` returns a formula (binomial series). Not equivalent, but perhaps useful.

Comment: @MichaelE2  But `SeriesCoefficient[Sqrt[(x - t)^2 + c^2], {x, Infinity, n}, 
 Assumptions -> t == 0]` still returns unevaluated.  Strange.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Is there a way to convert a series in `1/(x - t)^n` to one in terms of `1/x^n`? I don't recall any, but that's hardly definitive. I suspect that the formula for the OP's series is much more difficult, and *M* doesn't find it (if there is one).

Comment: @MichaelE2  I have been thinking along the same lines and believe it can be done.  However, I do not believe that `SeriesCoefficient[Sqrt[u^2 + c^2], {u, Infinity, n}]` is giving the correct answer, because the series must have `u` as its leading term.  See the result of `Series[Sqrt[c^2 + u^2], {u, Infinity, 5}]`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yep, they seemed to have messed the formula up. This seems correct: `SeriesCoefficient[Sqrt[1 + y], {y, 0, n}]`, and you can get the `u` series with `y == c^2/u^2` and multiplying the `y` series by `u`.

Comment: @J.M.  Because the method provided (`SeriesCoefficient`) for the seemingly duplicate question does not work for the present question, I recommend that the present question be reopened for other possible answers.

Comment: @bb, your last few comments, and Michael's, are sufficiently convincing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following result is based on comments above exchanged between Michael E2 and me.  Because

```
SeriesCoefficient[Sqrt[(x - t)^2 + c^2], {x, Infinity, n}]
```

returns unevaluated, and

```
SeriesCoefficient[Sqrt[u^2 + c^2], {u, Infinity, n}]
(* Piecewise[{{(c^2)^((1 + n)/2)*Binomial[1/2, -n/2], Mod[n, -2] == 0 && n <= 0}}, 0] *)
```

is manifestly incorrect (i.e., a bug), begin instead with

```
SeriesCoefficient[Sqrt[1 + z], {z, 0, n}];
s1 = %[[1, 1, 1]] (x - t) (c/(x - t))^(2 n)
(* (c/(-t + x))^(2 n) (-t + x) Binomial[1/2, n] *)
```

To test the correctness of this result, perform

```
Sum[s1, {n, 0, Infinity}] // Simplify
(* Sqrt[1 + c^2/(t - x)^2] (-t + x) *)
```

which is correct.  However, it is not the desired result, because the terms are functions of `x - t` instead of `x`.  So, expand `s1` in `t`.

```
SeriesCoefficient[(t - x)^(1 - 2 n), {t, 0, m}, Assumptions -> n >= 0];
s2 = Simplify[%[[1, 1, 1]] s1 (t - x)^-(1 - 2 n), x - t > 0 && n ∈ Integers] t^m
(* c^(2 n) t^m (-x)^(-m - 2 n) x Binomial[1/2, n] Binomial[1 - 2 n, m] *)
```

Again, a test produces the correct result.

```
Sum[s2, {n, 0, Infinity}, {m, 0, Infinity}] // Simplify
(* Sqrt[1 + c^2/(t - x)^2] (-t + x) *)
```

Finally, all terms of a given order in `x^-j` must be summed to obtain the desired result.  Doing so yields

```
f[j_] = Piecewise[{{x - t, j == 0}, {Sum[If[Mod[j + 1 - m, 2] == 0, 
    s2 /. x -> 1 /. n -> (j + 1 - m)/2, 0], {m, 0, j}] x^-j, j > 0}}];
```

To test its accuracy, compare it with the series expansion provided in the question.

```
Series[Sqrt[c^2 + (t - x)^2], {x, Infinity, 5}] // Normal
(* -t + (c^6 - 12 c^4 t^2 + 8 c^2 t^4)/(16 x^5) + (-3 c^4 t + 4 c^2 t^3)/(8 x^4) + 
   (-c^4 + 4 c^2 t^2)/(8 x^3) + (c^2 t)/(2 x^2) + c^2/(2 x) + x *)
FullSimplify[Sum[f[j], {j, 0, 5}] == %]
(* True *)
```

Thus, the sum of `f[j]` is the desired result.

All calculations were performed with

```
$Version
(* 11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017) *)
```

Comment: But I don't want it expanded out. For example consider $g(x) = a + ax + ax^2 + ax^3 + \cdots$ - I need Mathematica to give me this series in the form $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}ax^k$. That is what my question is about. Can this be done?

Comment: @eurocoder  Each of the answers gives an expression for a term in the series, which then can be summed.  In this case, the sum is `Sum[f[j], {j, 0, Infinity}]`.

Comment: Excellent, it outputs an actual summation expression cheers! These summations are giving me serious trouble..if you get a chance maybe you could take a look at my latest issue - https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144096/how-to-represent-fx-y-xk-logy-x-as-a-summation-of-the-form-fx

Answer (score 4):

[`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient) will work if one adjusts the expression so that it is finite as `x->Infinity`. So:

```
nthTerm = SeriesCoefficient[Sqrt[c^2+(t-x)^2]/x,{x,Infinity,n},Assumptions->n>=0];
nthTerm //InputForm

(*
DifferenceRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, 
{(-1 + \[FormalN])*(c^2 + t^2)*\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (-t - 2*\[FormalN]*t)*\[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] + 
  (2 + \[FormalN])*\[FormalY][2 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][0] == 1, \[FormalY][1] == -t}]][n]
*)
```

Hence, the desired sum is:

```
sum[t_] := Inactive[Sum][nthTerm x^(1-n), {n, 0, t}]
sum[Infinity] //InputForm

(*
Inactive[Sum][x^(1 - n)*DifferenceRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, 
 {(-1 + \[FormalN])*(c^2 + t^2)*\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (-t - 2*\[FormalN]*t)*\[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] + 
    (2 + \[FormalN])*\[FormalY][2 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][0] == 1, \[FormalY][1] == -t}]][n], {n, 0, Infinity}]
*)
```

Check:

```
Series[expr, {x, Infinity, 5}]//TeXForm
```

> $x-t+\frac{c^2}{2 x}+\frac{c^2 t}{2 x^2}+\frac{4 c^2 t^2-c^4}{8 x^3}+\frac{4 c^2 t^3-3 c^4
>    t}{8 x^4}+\frac{c^6-12 c^4 t^2+8 c^2 t^4}{16
>    x^5}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^6\right)$

```
Series[Activate@sum[6], {x, Infinity, 5}]//TeXForm
```

> $x-t+\frac{c^2}{2 x}+\frac{c^2 t}{2 x^2}+\frac{\frac{c^2
>    t^2}{2}-\frac{c^4}{8}}{x^3}+\frac{\frac{c^2 t^3}{2}-\frac{3 c^4
>    t}{8}}{x^4}+\frac{c^6-12 c^4 t^2+8 c^2 t^4}{16
>    x^5}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^6\right)$

Comment: Executing the first line of your answer (with version 11.1 on Windows 10), I do not obtain the same expression for the `DifferenceRoot`.  Specifically, the initial conditions within the `DifferenceRoot` that I obtain are `\[FormalY][0] == 0, \[FormalY][1] == 0`.  As a consequence, `DifferenceRoot` evaluates to zero for all `n`.  What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Maybe you have some lingering definitions? I get the above result in M9, M10.3.1 and some developmental version of M11.1.

Comment: I can reproduce your result with 10.4.1 but not with 11.1, both on Windows 10 (64 bit).  In each case I rebooted my computer before running a fresh session of Mathematica, and the line of code in question was the first line of the notebook.  I do not doubt your answer, which is excellent (+1), but I do suspect a bug in 11.1.

Comment: The same is not true of the bug that @MichaelE2 and I identified in our comments above.  It occurs for both 10.4.1 and 11.1.  Just now, I also ran SeriesCoefficient[Sqrt[c^2 + (u)^2]/u, {u, Infinity, n}], patterned after your answer, but the incorrect answer persisted.

Comment: @MichaelE2, Carl Woll  -  I have reported these issues to Wolfram, Inc as CASE:3873213.  It is not clear to me that the question should be tagged as "bugs", however, because it is not central to the issues reported.

Comment: @CarlWoll But I don't want it expanded out. For example consider $g(x) = a + ax + ax^2 + ax^3 + \cdots$ - I need Mathematica to give me this series in the form $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}ax^k$. That is what my question is about. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Still another approach is to use `FindSequenceFunction`, which should work whenever the series coefficients satisfy a recurrence relation that is not too complicated.  Begin by obtaining the list of coefficients of the series.

```
coef = Series[Sqrt[c^2 + (t - x)^2], {x, Infinity, 8}][[3]]
(* {1, -t, c^2/2, (c^2 t)/2, 1/8 (-c^4 + 4 c^2 t^2), 1/8 (-3 c^4 t + 4 c^2 t^3), 
    1/16 (c^6 - 12 c^4 t^2 + 8 c^2 t^4), 1/16 (5 c^6 t - 20 c^4 t^3 + 8 c^2 t^5), 
    1/128 (-5 c^8 + 120 c^6 t^2 - 240 c^4 t^4 + 64 c^2 t^6), 
    1/128 (-35 c^8 t + 280 c^6 t^3 - 336 c^4 t^5 + 64 c^2 t^7)} *)
```

Then apply `FindSequenceFunction` and, since the result is a `DifferenceRoot`, discard any superfluous initial conditions.

```
FindSequenceFunction[coef];
ReplacePart[%, {1, 2} -> %[[1, 2, 1 ;; 3]]]
(* DifferenceRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {(-2 + \[FormalN]) (c^2 + t^2) 
   \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (t - 2 \[FormalN] t) \[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] 
   + (1 + \[FormalN]) \[FormalY][2 + \[FormalN]] == 0, 
   \[FormalY][1] == 1, \[FormalY][2] == -t}]] *)
```

Not surprisingly, this result is equivalent to that in the earlier answer by Carl Woll.  It is validated by

```
Simplify[Table[%[n], {n, 10}] == coef]
(* True *)
```