# How to represent $f(x) = (y-x)^k \log(y-x)$ as a summation of the form $f(x) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty \cdots$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, series-expansion, summation, expression-manipulation

I am having a lot of trouble working with summations in Mathematica, and this is unfortunate as it is my main use case for the application My latest summation issue is the following. I am trying to determine a summation expression of the form:
$$f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \cdots$$
for the function
$$f(x) = (y-x)^k \log(y-x),$$
where $x$ is expanded around $0$ and $k$ is an integer that is greater than or equal to $1$.

My code is as follows:

```
expr = Series[(y - x)^k*Log[y - x], {x, 0, 5}] // Normal
toΣ@expr
```

I attempted to use this code as it was suggested in a previous question. I believe the first line determines the summation and the second line puts it in the required form. However it doesn't work and I get the following output (which I have truncated at second order):

```
Out[1]: y^j Log[y]-x y^(-1+j) (1+j Log[y])+1/2 x^2 y^(-2+j) (-1+2 j-j Log[y]+j^2 Log[y])

Out[2]: toΣ[y^j Log[y]-x y^(-1+j) (1+j Log[y])+1/2 x^2 y^(-2+j) (-1+2 j-j Log[y]+j^2 Log[y])]
```

So what can I do to convert this expression into a clear and concise representation of the following form:
$$f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \cdots$$

Comment: Your results suggest that you have not defined `toΣ`.  However, note that  `toΣ` relies on `FindSequenceFunction`, which is returning unevaluated.  In general, `FindSequenceFunction` only works for fairly simple sequences, which this is not.

Comment: See my alternative answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Complete rewrite of answer**

The expression to be expanded as a series is the argument of

```
ser = Series[(y - x)^k*Log[y - x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

I attempted to obtain the result in an earlier version of this answer by means of `SeriesCoefficient` but obtain an incorrect result, because I failed specify that `k` is a nonnegative integer.  The answer provided by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) in a comment below, which does specify `k` as a nonnegative integer, involves a `DifferenceRoot` that does not evaluate for `n > 1`.  Here is a workaround.  The `Log` and `Power` terms of the expression can be expanded separately and then combined as follows.

```
sc1 = SeriesCoefficient[(y - x)^k, {x, 0, n1}]
(* Piecewise[{{(-1)^n1*y^(k - n1)*Binomial[k, n1], n1 >= 0}}, 0] *)

sc2 = SeriesCoefficient[Log[y - x], {x, 0, n2}]
(* Piecewise[{{(-1)^(1 + n2)/(n2*(-y)^n2), n2 >= 1}, {Log[y], n2 == 0}}, 0] *)
```

The corresponding series coefficient of the product then is

```
c[n_] := Sum[sc1 sc2 /. n2 -> n - n1, {n1, 0, n}]
```

and `Sum` for the original expression is

```
Sum[c[n] x^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

To test the validity of this expression, compare it with `ser`.

```
Simplify[Sum[c[n] x^n, {n, 0, 5}] == ser // Normal]
(* True *)
```

Note that `Sum` will try to recover the original expression, so it may be necessary to use `Inactivate` to prevent this, depending on how the `Sum` is to be used.  (My thanks to [MaTECmatica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4320/matecmatica) for suggesting that `Inactivate` is superior to `Hold` in this instance.)

**Addendum**

The `Sum` in the formula for `c` can be performed symbolically, although the result is complicated.

```
innersum = FullSimplify[c[n], k >= 0 && k ∈ Integers && n >= 0 && n ∈ Integers];
innersum[[1, 1, 1]] = Simplify[innersum[[1, 1, 1]] /. n -> 0];
innersum[[1, 1, 2]] = n == 0; innersum
(* Piecewise[{{y^k*Log[y], n == 0}, {-(y^(-1 + k)*(1 + k*Log[y])), n == 1}}, 
   ((-1)^n*y^(-1 + k - n)*((1 + k - n)*y*Binomial[k, -1 + n]*(HarmonicNumber[k] - 
   HarmonicNumber[k - n]) + n*(y*Binomial[k, n]*Hypergeometric2F1[1, -k + n, 1 + n, y^(-1)]
   + Binomial[k, 1 + n]*Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - k + n, 2 + n, y^(-1)])*Log[y]))/n] *)
```

The second and third lines of code perform further simplification for `n == 0`.

Comment: Instead of Hold, the op might want to use Inactivate[Sum[c[n] x^n, {n, 0, Infinity}], Sum] so that c[n] is replaced in the expression without calculating the Sum

Comment: @MaTECmatica  Excellent point.  Thanks.

Comment: I would use `Assuming[k>0 && Element[k, Integers], SeriesCoefficient[..]]` instead, as the result you give doesn't work for positive integer k (as requested by the OP).

Comment: @bbgodfrey I really appreciate the help, I can use this approach for other summations now and it will save me so much time not having to manually derive these series like I had been doing!

Answer (score 7):

You can use a old trick:
$$\frac{\partial (y-x)^{t+k}}{\partial t}\text{/.}\, t\to 0=(-x+y)^k \log (-x+y)$$

The corresponding series coefficient  is:

```
sc = SeriesCoefficient[(y - x)^(t + k), {x, 0, n}]
(* Piecewise[{{(-1)^n*y^(k - n + t)*Binomial[k + t, n], n >= 0}}, 0]*)
```

Compute derivative respect to `t` and `t=0`:

```
FullSimplify[(D[sc[[1, 1, 1]], t] /. t -> 0), Assumptions -> 
n >= 0 && n \[Element] Integers && k >= 0 && k \[Element] Integers]
(* (-1)^n y^(k - n)Binomial[k, n] (HarmonicNumber[k] - HarmonicNumber[k - n] + Log[y]) *)

c[n_] := (-1)^n y^(k - n)*Binomial[k, n] (HarmonicNumber[k] - HarmonicNumber[k - n] + Log[y])
```

Series coefficient is simpler as previously presented by [bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey).

and `Sum` for the  expression is:

```
 Sum[c[n] x^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

> $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (-1)^n x^n y^{k-n} \binom{k}{n} \left(H_k-H_{k-n}+\log (y)\right)$$

To test the validity of this expression, compare it for `k=1`:

```
 Series[(y - x)^k*Log[y - x] /. k -> 1, {x, 0, 5}] // Normal // Expand
```

> $-x+\frac{x^5}{20 y^4}+\frac{x^4}{12 y^3}+\frac{x^3}{6 y^2}+\frac{x^2}{2 y}-x \log (y)+y \log (y)$

```
 Sum[Limit[c[n]*x^n, k -> 1], {n, 0, 5}] // FullSimplify // Expand
```

> $-x+\frac{x^5}{20 y^4}+\frac{x^4}{12 y^3}+\frac{x^3}{6 y^2}+\frac{x^2}{2 y}-x \log (y)+y \log (y)$

```
 (* True *)
```